# SharePoint 2019/Project Server 2019 Sync AD problems

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, active-directory, project-server

I'm trying to create sync through AD in Project Server using Active Directory Resource Pool Synchronization. When I try to save config, no action and in ULS log i get this:

```
UsageLoggedSqlSession: Before executing command against SP_Config. Command is dbo.proc_checkSubscriptionIdExistsInFarm
Singleton lookup of site subscription failed. Id = 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
PWA:http://site/timesheets, ServiceApp:Project TimeSheets, PSI: Could not find a subscription
PWA:http://site/timesheets, ServiceApp:Project TimeSheets, PSI: GetActiveDirectorySyncEnterpriseResourcePoolSettings3: Tenant Distinguished Name not found
PWA:http://site/timesheets,User:30da660b-ca17-e911-8420-aac560ed3e41-ADSyncERP picker ResolvedEntities: <name>c:0+.w|s-1-5-21-329068152-842925246-1708537768-1280</name>
Entering Monitored Scope (Project Server SubDal:FillTypedDataSet -- pjpub.MSP_ADMIN_ReadAdSyncSettings(StoredProcedure)). Parent=Invoking business object method PWA.ResolveActiveDirectoryGroups
Leaving Monitored Scope: (Project Server SubDal:FillTypedDataSet -- pjpub.MSP_ADMIN_ReadAdSyncSettings(StoredProcedure)) Execution Time=0.3558; CPU Milliseconds=0; SQL Query Count=1; Parent=Invoking business object method PWA.ResolveActiveDirectoryGroups
```

Comment: You have to be more specific. What is your problem? What does not work? What have you tried? What version of SharePoint do you have?

Comment: I'm trying to use in Project Server 2019 (Active Directory Resource Pool Syncronization). I want to use AD group to sync users. Every time i get that problem. SharePoint 2019 version: 16.0.10340.12101

Comment: I have exact same error and log with you. Have you resolved the issue?